# Migrate SSAS Database from MSSQL 2005 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, ssas, business-intelligence

Want to upgrade `SQL Server Analytic Services (SSAS)` all cubes and dimensions from `MSSQL-Server 2005 to 2012`, Along with the `SSAS` Database data.

I have already upgraded the `SSAS` Project in Visual Studio(SSDT) using Upgrade Adviser, But I am not sure whether this is the right way or not?

So, please guide/suggest to upgrade SSAS `Database from 2005 to 2012`.
Also is it possible to move Directly from `sql-server 2005` to `sql-server 2012`? or i need to go step by step from `2005→2008→2012` ??

Please guide. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok to move from 2005 directly to 2012.

I usually do this way:

- create XMLA backup on 2005
- restore it on 2012

Two possible issues I faced several times:

1. if XMLA is not restoring because of "preserve null" (do not remember
   exact name) for Distinct Count measure -- change this option to
   "Automatic" in XMLA directly and re-run again. has to work.
2. for huge cubes (1TB+) I also switch off all calculations (just comment them
   out). because it is validating at the end of processing and roll
   everything back if any calculation is not valid because of upgrade.

Comment: Is it okay to upgrade entire SSAS project using Upgrade Adviser? I have only done so, anything else i need to do after that?

Comment: I think no, that is enough.

Comment: Could not understand about XMLA backup and restore. But i tried Normal Backup and Restore and its worked. Thanks Alex

Comment: XMLA backup - it's metadata backup only (w/o real data that is saved in .abf classic backup). It's useful because it's small (even huge cubes metadata size is 10...20MB), so we usually do XMLA backups and process data after that to make cube browsable. For example, to make a full copy of a DB: do XMLA backup into file, open this file and change DB ID and DB Name, execute it: voila, new DB copy is ready to be processed!

Comment: Yes @Alex, I had googling for same. Understood your point very well. thank you very much for your Guidance Alex.